# Tweetable Coffee Pot- Python Indent Error

Tags: python, indentation

I am trying to replicate this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tweet-a-Pot-Twitter-Enabled-Coffee-Pot/step4/The-Code-Python-Side) and I'm pretty new to Python.

When I try to run that Python code I keep getting a mixture of `Unexpected Indent Errors` and `Unexpected Indent Blocks`.

I have looked at the indents in the program. If I try to remove them I still get the error on another line if I check the program again.

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the code from the Instructable.

```
#******************************************#
# Tweet-a-Pot by Gregg Horton 2011 #
# Please email changes or #
# updates to greggawatt@instructables.com #
# *****************************************#

 ##Import Libraries

 import twitter
 import serial
 import time

 ##authenticate yourself with twitter
 api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumerkeyhere', consumer_secret='consumersecrethere', access_token_key='accesskey', access_token_secret='accesssecret')

 ##set to your serial port
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200)

 ## check serial port
 def checkokay():
 ser.flushInput()
 time.sleep(3)
 line=ser.readline()
 time.sleep(3)

 if line == ' ':
 line=ser.readline()
 print 'here'
 ## Welcome message
 print 'Welcome To Drip Twit!'
 print 'Making Coffee..'
 def driptwit():
 status = [ ]
 x = 0

 status = api.GetUserTimeline('X') ##grab latest statuses

 checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

 drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

 ## check for match and write to serial if match
 if drip[0] == '#driptwit':
 print 'Tweet Recieved, Making Coffee'
 ser.write('1')
 elif drip[0] == '#driptwitstop': ##break if done
 ser.write('0')
 print 'stopped, awaiting instructions.'
 else:
 ser.write('0')
 print 'Awaiting Tweet'


 while 1:
 driptwit() ## call driptwit function
 time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

Comment: maybe you should check a python tutorial. Answer will be near first paragraph of the first chapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, Python is indentation-sensitive! Your whole code is invalid.

```
#******************************************#
# Tweet-a-Pot by Gregg Horton 2011 #
# Please email changes or #
# updates to greggawatt@instructables.com #
# *****************************************#

##Import Libraries

import twitter
import serial
import time

##authenticate yourself with twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumerkeyhere', consumer_secret='consumersecrethere', access_token_key='accesskey', access_token_secret='accesssecret')

##set to your serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200)

## check serial port
def checkokay():
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    line=ser.readline()
    time.sleep(3)

    if line == ' ':
        line=ser.readline()
        print 'here'
        ## Welcome message
        print 'Welcome To Drip Twit!'
        print 'Making Coffee..'
def driptwit():
    status = [ ]
    x = 0

    status = api.GetUserTimeline('X') ##grab latest statuses

    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

    ## check for match and write to serial if match
    if drip[0] == '#driptwit':
        print 'Tweet Recieved, Making Coffee'
        ser.write('1')
        elif drip[0] == '#driptwitstop': ##break if done
        ser.write('0')
        print 'stopped, awaiting instructions.'
        else:
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Awaiting Tweet'


while 1:
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
    time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

Comment: I figured it was, I'm new to Python though and I'm not sure how many indents and whatnot to put in the code. What I had was taken directly from the Instructable. :/ Thanks so much it is working now with the indents!

Comment: You're welcome! If this solves your question, please do accept it! The button is on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space, then add the correct indentation to each line. Good luck.

I got bored and did the indentation for you

```
#******************************************#
# Tweet-a-Pot by Gregg Horton 2011         #
# Please email changes or                  # 
# updates to greggawatt@instructables.com  #
# so i can keep it updated         #
# *****************************************#

##Import Libraries

import twitter
import serial
import time

##authenticate yourself with twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='your key here', consumer_secret='your key here', access_token_key='your key here',
                  access_token_secret='your here here')

##set to your serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200)

## check serial port
def checkokay():
    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(3)
    line = ser.readline()
    time.sleep(3)

    if line == ' ':
        line = ser.readline()
    print 'here'

## Welcome message
print 'Welcome To Drip Twit!'


def driptwit():
    status = []
    x = 0

    status = api.GetUserTimeline('yourusername') ##grab latest statuses

    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array

    drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words

    ## check for match and write to serial if match
    if drip[0] == '#driptwit':
        print 'Tweet Recieved, Making Coffee'
        ser.write('1')
    elif drip[0] == '#driptwitstop': ##break if done
        ser.write('0')
        print 'stopped, awaiting instructions.'
    else:
        ser.write('0')
        print 'Awaiting Tweet'


while 1:
    driptwit() ## call driptwit function
    time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```